# How to get variables from ansible result

Tags: ansible

I have a shell script whose output is an echo of the following format
`<variable_1>;<variable_2>;<variable_3>` etc

I want to use these variables and run a mysql query to update a DB like so
`mysql -u<user> -p<password> -h<host> -e'insert into test_table values ("variable_1","variable_2","variable_3")'`

My ansible playbook looks like this.

```
---
- hosts: infoServers
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: gather info
    script: get_hostdata.sh
    register: result
  - name: print result
    local_action: command mysql -uuser -ppassword -h192.168.101.10 ansible_db -e'insert into test_table values ("{{ item[0] }}","{{ item[1] }}","{{ item[3] }});'
    with_items: [ result.stdout.split(';')[0], result.stdout.split(';')[1], result.stdout.split(';')[2] ]
```

ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, test_variables.yml

Basically i want to be able to use the output of a shell command, split it into some variables and be able to use those in further ansible actions.
Can you please guide me on how to access the variables correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get an error like this you really should provide the full details of the error message.  When I cut and paste your playbook into a file and tried to run it I got the following:

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, ff.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 11, column 43

    local_action: command mysql -uuser -ppassword -h192.168.101.10 ansible_db -e'insert into test_table values ("{{ item[0] }}","{{ item[1] }}","{{ item[3] }});'
    with_items: [ result.stdout.split(';')[0], result.stdout.split(';')[1], result.stdout.split(';')[2] ]
                                          ^
```

So it appears, if this matches up with the full error you were receiving that the syntax of your with_items clause is wrong.

I'm not sure why you're even trying to do this using with_items.  All you're effectively doing in this case is some unnecessary variable substitution.  The following should also do exactly what you want:

```
- name: print result
    local_action: command mysql -uuser -ppassword -h192.168.101.10 ansible_db -e'insert into test_table values ("{{ result.stdout.split(';')[0] }}","{{ result.stdout.split(';')[1] }}","{{ result.stdout.split(';')[2] }}");'
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have one more doubt - what if i want to assign the value of result.stdout.split(';')[1] to another variable (say var_1) and then use var_1 later to check some conditions etc .. what would be the correct way to accomplish this

Comment: You can do this via the [set_fact](http://docs.ansible.com/set_fact_module.html) task: set_fact: var1: result.stdout.split(';')[1]  var2: result.stdout.split(';')[2] etc.

Comment: I have tried this solution in the latest version of ansible and keep being told "list object has no element 1".  It definitely does as the line before I printed out the same split statement (without the array reference) using a debug and it prints out the result as 3 separate entries... what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote and use `{{}}` correctly.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tags: s16
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - shell: echo 'variable_1;variable_2;variable_3'
    register: result
  - local_action: debug msg="values ("{{ item[0] }}","{{ item[1] }}","{{ item[3] }}");'"
    with_items: [ "{{result.stdout.split(';')[0]}}", "{{result.stdout.split(';')[1]}}", "{{result.stdout.split(';')[2]}}" ]
```

Will print something like:

```
TASK: [debug msg="values ("{{ item[0] }}","{{ item[1] }}","{{ item[3] }}");'"] *** 
ok: [localhost -> 127.0.0.1] => (item=variable_1) => {
    "item": "variable_1", 
    "msg": "values (\"v\",\"a\",\"i\");'"
}
ok: [localhost -> 127.0.0.1] => (item=variable_2) => {
    "item": "variable_2", 
    "msg": "values (\"v\",\"a\",\"i\");'"
}
ok: [localhost -> 127.0.0.1] => (item=variable_3) => {
    "item": "variable_3", 
    "msg": "values (\"v\",\"a\",\"i\");'"
}
```

As you can see with `item[0], .., item[2]` you're indexing into the string `"variable_1"` instead of the array `["variable_1","variable_2","variable_3"]`

Simplest (and a lot more performant) way to do this would be:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tags: s17
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - shell: echo 'variable_1;variable_2;variable_3'
    register: result
- debug: msg="insert into tt values ("{{result.stdout|replace(';', '","')}}");'"
```