# How to get postgresql_query results from Ansible

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I'm trying to print the output of PostgreSQL query that is run by Ansible.  Unfortunately I'm not sure how to get ahold of the return value.

```
    - name: Get specific tables
      postgresql_query:
        db: "{{ database_name }}"
        login_host: "{{ my_host }}"
        login_user: "{{ my_user }}"
        login_password: "{{ my_password }}"
        query: SELECT * FROM pg_tables t WHERE t.tableowner = current_user
```

Googling just says to use `register:`, but the PostgreSQL ansible module does not have a `register` param:

```
fatal: [xx.xxx.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (postgresql_query) module: register Supported parameters include: ca_cert, db, login_host, login_password, login_unix_socket, login_user, named_args, path_to_script, port, positional_args, query, session_role, ssl_mode"}
```

The [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/postgresql_query_module.html#return-values) list return values for this module but there are no examples on how to use them, and everything I search for [leads right back to `register:`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29374522/3316036).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you are very close, but have `register` at the wrong indentation. It's a parameter of the task itself, not the postgresql module.

Try:

```
    - name: Get specific tables
      postgresql_query:
        db: "{{ database_name }}"
        login_host: "{{ my_host }}"
        login_user: "{{ my_user }}"
        login_password: "{{ my_password }}"
        query: SELECT * FROM pg_tables t WHERE t.tableowner = current_user
      register: result

    - debug:
        var: result
```

Comment: I don't know whether to be relieved or frustrated that I missed the obvious :D.

Thank you!