# Anisble django postgres how to get user account or see if user exists

Tags: django, database, postgresql, count, ansible

I need to determine if any users exist in a Django site using postgresql. I'm using ansible to update the sites including building new sites. If the site is not new, I check to make sure the database does not exist. If not, I create the database and the superuser. The next time the system runs, it knows not to create the database, but when it goes to create the superuser again, I get a fatal error. Hence, I need to check on if there are users in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found [How to get postgresql_query results from Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57487357/how-to-get-postgresql-query-results-from-ansible) pointed me in the direction to get a solution.

```
 - name: Get user count from database
   postgresql_query:
     db: '{{ django_software }}'
     query: SELECT * FROM auth_user
   register: qresult
   become: yes
   become_user: postgres
```

The I can use qresult.rowcount to determine if any users exist. I can also add a WHERE clause to the SELECT to determine if a particular user exists.